# How to use SQL ROW_NUMBER with INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written this query to get data for special keyword:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetAllSpecialPaperTags]
    @PKeyword nvarchar(200)
as
begin
   select 
      Papers.PID, Papers.PTitle, Papers.PaperSummary 
  from 
      PaperKeywords 
  left join 
      PaperTags on PaperKeywords.PKeyID = PaperTags.PKeyID
  left join 
      Papers on PaperTags.PID = Papers.PID 
  where 
      PaperKeywords.PKeyword = @PKeyword
end
```

I want use this article for custom paging : [Custom Paging using SQL Server Stored Procedure](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Custom-Paging-in-ASP.Net-GridView-using-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure.aspx)

I wrote this query but I'm getting an error:

```
create procedure [dbo].[GetAllSpecialPaperTags]
   @PageIndex INT = 1
   ,@PageSize INT = 10
   ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
   ,@PKeyword nvarchar(200)
as
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            ORDER BY [Papers.PID] ASC
      )AS RowNumber
    ,Papers.PID , Papers.PTitle , Papers.PaperSummary
     INTO #Results
      from PaperKeywords 
        left join PaperTags on PaperKeywords.PKeyID = PaperTags.PKeyID
        left join Papers on PaperTags.PID = Papers.PID where PaperKeywords.PKeyword = @PKeyword

      SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
      FROM #Results

      SELECT * FROM #Results
      WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

      DROP TABLE #Results
end
```

Error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetAllSpecialPaperTags, Line 11
>   Invalid column name 'Papers.PID'.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your `order by` expression:

```
        ORDER BY [Papers.PID] ASC
```

It is looking for a column named in its entirety "Papers.PID".  It is *not* looking for the `PID` column in `Papers`.  Just drop the braces:

```
        ORDER BY Papers.PID ASC
```